# There is a list, the first, and last element have rounded edges with nth-last-child and nth-first-child

Tags: html, css

```
a{
    border-radius: 0;
}
a:first-child a{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
a:last-child a{
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px ;
}
```

img1:
[image: img1]
img2:
[image: img2]

Moreover, all elements between them are without rounding. The fact is that the number of these elements is always different, from one to infinity. Question! How to round all edges with CSS if there is only one element?

Comment: you could use the more specific `border-top-left-radius` `border-top-right-radius` `border-bottom-left-radius` `border-bottom-right-radius`

Comment: assuming they're generated, you can add class if the array length is 1

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for your example:

```
a{
    border-radius: 0;
}
a:first-child a{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
a:last-child a{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i get it now :)

Comment: THX! I'm so stupid!!))

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, there's nothing stupid about asking questions @Megasort